# How do I get the output to only be numbers within a list that are greater than x?

Tags: python, list

```
def list_number(mylist,x):
    y=[i if i>x else False for i in mylist]
    return y
```

I am trying to get only the numbers that are greater than `x` in a list to be my output and I also need it to `return False` if there are no numbers greater than `x`.

For example `mylist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and `x=5`, I want my output to be `[6,7,8,9]`.
if `x=10`, I want my output to be false.

I cannot use any methods like `.append` or `.sort`

Comment: Who came up with the silly requirement to return `False` instead of an empty list? That's somewhere between irrelevant and inconvenient...

Comment: Or did you actually mean your "I want my output to be false"? Because an empty list *is* false.

Comment: @KellyBundy: To be technical, an empty list is not really `False`. `([] is not False) == True`. But I understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Feline I didn't say it's `False`. I said it's false. Which it is.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's true and `True`.

Comment: @Feline Hmm, I don't why you say it's `True`.

Comment: @KellyBundy it's a joke

Answer (score 4):

The mistake in your example is your incorrect usage of [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Here are simple examples to show you how to use list comprehension with conditional statements:

```py
iterator = range(10)
# Example (list comprehension with if statement)
[x for x in iterator if x > 5]
# [6, 7, 8, 9]

# Example (list comprehension with if...else statement)
[x if x > 5 else 0 for x in iterator]
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

As for your specific question, you can use the information above to create a function like this:

```py
def list_number(mylist, x):
    y = [n for n in mylist if n > x]
    if not y:
      return False
    return y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and then return False if the list is empty. Using the `or` operator allow it to simplify it as it will execute the second statement if the first one is considered as False, so if the list is empty.

```py
def list_number(mylist, x):
    return [y for y in mylist if y > x] or False
```

---

Another way it can be done is using a filter:

```py
def list_number(mylist, x):
     return list(filter(x.__lt__, mylist)) or False
```

`x.__lt__` correspond to the less than operator on the value of x.

---

Either way,

```py
>>> list_number(list(range(10)), 5)
[6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> list_number(list(range(10)), 11)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that empty list is a **false** value in python.
This way your code will always return a list, which is much better than returning a List | boolean

```
from typing import List

def list_number(my_list: List[int], x: int) -> List[int]:
    return [num for num in my_list if num > x]

result: List[int] = list_number([4,6,89,21],7)
if(result):
  print('non empty result')
else:
  print('empty result')
  
result: List[int] = list_number([4,6,89,21],790)
if(result):
  print('non empty result')
else:
  print('empty result')
```

output

```
non empty result
empty result
```

Comment: The function is supposed to return false when the list is empty. `Union[bool, List[int]]`

Comment: @YohannBoniface yeah but it is not logical. You can treat empty list as a falsy value. OP is probably not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this code is pretty easy to read and predictable. No need to have any advanced knowledge. (except typehints)

```py
from typing import List, Union

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x = 10


def greater_than(list_uf_nums: List[int], num: int) -> Union[List[int], bool]:
    return_list = [y for y in list_uf_nums if y > num]
    if not return_list:
        return False
    return return_list


print(greater_than(l, x))
```

Comment: You can use `or` to simplify this statement

Comment: But that doesn't mean it is wrong.

Comment: You forgot to import `Union` from `typing`.